# Accept lists of computers in many forms in a Powershell pipeline

Tags: powershell, pipeline

I am trying to create a script that accepts lists of computers in various forms from many different 3rd party sources that I don't control.  These various sources return computers sometimes as a simple array of strings, sometimes as a Powershell Object, sometimes as a hash.  I want my script to take any of these types of lists and get the computer name(s), put it in an array.  Then perform the actual processing.

Here are some examples of data that might be given to my script that I am trying to create.

```
@('system-01','system-02') | \\path\share\mycommand.ps1

@(@{"ComputerName" = "system-01";OtherKey = 'foo'},
  @{"ComputerName" = "system-02";OtherKey = 'foo'}) | \\path\share\mycommand.ps1

@([PSCustomObject]@{
    ComputerName = 'system-01'
    OtherProperties = 'foo'
  },
  [PSCustomObject]@{
    ComputerName = 'system-02'
    OtherProperties = 'foo'
  }) | \\path\share\mycommand.ps1
```

My script currently looks like.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
    ValueFromPipeline=$True,
    ParameterSetName="ComputerHash")]
    [hashtable]$ComputerHash,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
    ValueFromPipeline=$True,
    ParameterSetName="ComputerArray")]
    [String[]]$ComputerName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
    ValueFromPipeline=$True,
    ParameterSetName="ComputerObject")]
    [Object[]]$ComputerObjects
)
BEGIN
{
    # create an empty array to build up a list of the computers
    $computers=@()
}
PROCESS
{
    # get all the computers from the pipeline
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
    {
        "ComputerArray" { $computers+=$ComputerName; break}
        "ComputerHash"  { $computers+=$ComputerHash.ComputerName; break}
        "ComputerObject"{ $computers+=$ComputerObjects.ComputerName; break}
    }
}
END
{
    $computers | % { 
        # do the stuff
        "Do something on $_"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am currently getting the `Parameter set cannot be resolved ...` error.  How do I make my script so that it will basically accept any kind of pipeline input, and then do the right thing?  Is there some simpler method I should be using?

Answer (score 4):

What you could do, instead of making different parameter sets, is to just deal with it after you get the info. So something like:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
    ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $ComputerList
)
BEGIN
{
    # create an empty array to build up a list of the computers
    $computers=Switch($ComputerList.GetType()){
        {$_.Name -eq 'Hashtable'}{$ComputerList.ComputerName;Continue}
        {$ComputerList -is [Array] -and $ComputerList[0] -is [String]}{$ComputerList;Continue}
        {$ComputerList -is [Array] -and $ComputerList[0] -is [Object]}{$ComputerList.ComputerName}
    }
}
PROCESS
{
}
END
{
    $computers | % { 
        # do the stuff
        "Do something on $_"
    }
}
```

Or maybe even easier:

```
BEGIN{$Computers=If($ComputerList[0] -is [String]){$ComputerList}Else{$ComputerList.ComputerName}}
```

**Edit:** As pointed out, we don't get the piped data in the BEGIN or END blocks, so my idea works, but my script doesn't. Instead we have to do things in the PROCESS block as Zoredache has stated. He already posted his code, and I'm sure it works wonderfully, but I figured I'd post a modified version of mine so my answer wouldn't continue to be wrong, because, well, I don't like having wrong answers out there.

```
Function Test-Function1{
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
    ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $ComputerList
)
BEGIN
{
}
PROCESS
{    
    [string[]]$computers+=Switch($ComputerList){
        {$_ -is [Hashtable]}{$_.ComputerName;Continue}
        {$_ -is [String]}{$_;Continue}
        {$_ -is [Object]}{$_|Select -Expand Computer*}
    }
}
END
{
    $computers | % { 
        # do the stuff
        "Do something on $_"
    }
}
}
```

Then when I piped data to it as such:

```
@{'ComputerName'='Server1','Server2'}|Test-Function1
[pscustomobject]@{'Computer'='Server1'},[pscustomobject]@{'ComputerName'='Server2'}|Test-Function1
'Server1','Server2'|Test-Function1
```

They all responded with the expected output of:

```
Do something on Server1
Do something on Server2
```

Comment:  this is beautiful ^^ if I may add something, it's important to note you don't need `Break`s in PowerShell's `switch`. Why did you use the `Continue`s, though ?

Comment: @sodawillow I'm sure `Continue` was used to ensure the last clause was not validated and put extra information in the pipe.

Comment: While this certainly has gotten me to the a good spot, this doesn't work since pipeline input doesn't become available until the `Process` section.  If you try using this code as is with the input described in my question you get an error `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`  I have added the final code I used.

Comment: Continue is used so that any item does not validate twice on accident, and it's a habit of mine to make things move faster since I have some switches that can be fairly lengthy on a per-item basis.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten that pipeline input doesn't hit the Begin scriptblock. Good catch! Since you don't seem to actually do anything in the Process block aside from get the computername string, you could just move this to the End block and it should work fine there I think. Haven't tested that, but it seems like it should work ok there.

Comment: AFAIK The end block Also doesn't get all the pipeline input.  You only get it in the process block.  But I do the majority of the work in my script in the end block because for the processing I do, I need to have the entire list of computers available.  My simple `$computers | % { # do stuff` was just something basic so the question would have a mostly working bit of code for people to test with.

Answer (score 1):

@TheMadTechnician pointed me in the right direction, but his code seemed to have some errors, and didn't quiet work the way I wanted.  Here is the code that seems to do everything I want.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,
    ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $PipelineItem
)
BEGIN
{
    $ComputerList=@()
}
PROCESS
{
    $ComputerList+=
        Switch($PipelineItem.GetType()) {
            {$_.Name -eq 'String'}
                {$PipelineItem}
            {$_.Name -eq 'Hashtable'}
                {$PipelineItem.ComputerName}
            {$_.Name -eq 'PSCustomObject' -and (Get-Member -MemberType Properties -Name "Computer" -InputObject $PipelineItem)}
                {$PipelineItem.Computer}
            {$_.Name -eq 'PSCustomObject' -and (Get-Member -MemberType Properties -Name "ComputerName" -InputObject $PipelineItem)}
                {$PipelineItem.ComputerName}
        }
}
END
{
    $ComputerList | % {
        # do the stuff
        "Do something on $_"
    }
}
```